# lastKnownLocation is always returning null when gps is off

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, google-play-services, location-services

I am using Google Service API , LocationServices.FusedLocationApi to find user's current and then updated Location. I have tested on emulator as well as on actual device and I have found that if I turn off GPS LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() always returns null, however I get a valid value if I turn on the GPS. Here is the code which I am using:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastKnownLocation;
mLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude()));
    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()));
}

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, createLocationRequest(), this);
```

Am I missing something here? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u should check if the your device has a GPS first by using this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }

 private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

And then use the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)`.

For more info and code please refer [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bojie/locationex/MapsActivity.java).

Comment: @bijang Thanks for the answer and detailed code. I am trying to understand that if GPS is disabled then what happens? Currently if GPS is disabled then it does not show my location, how can I fix this?

Comment: Two ways to get your current location: 1. From `GPS`, you need to have GPS and enable it. 2. From `Network Location Provider`, but this is not accuracy than GPS. For more details, please refer [here](http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/).

Comment: I got the problem, I was under impression that network location provider would work even if location is disabled. but that is not the case. Location has to be enabled if I have to find location (Different mode of location). Thanks for the help